# how to replace every 100 lines with commas in python?

Tags: python

I have a txt file which has 1k lines.

After 100 lines i want to replace \r\n with ,
example:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

Will be:

```
1,2,3,4,5
6,7,8,9,10
....
```

Which will result in 2 lines 1,2,3..
and 6,7...

Comment: do you mean 10 lines?

Comment: Your example is confusing. Firstly, do you mean that you want to leave the first 100 lines unchanged and then change all lines n>100? Also, in your example of 10 numbers where you did the replacement why are they not all on the same line, unless there is a max line length of 5?

Comment: Are you expecting me to add 100 lines i just gaved an example. So i want for each 100 lines to replace them with \r\n which will be a,b,c,d,f... to 100, and after 100 lines again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
with open("Your/File/Path", "r+") as f:
    content = [(x.replace("\r\n", ", ") if i % 100 != 0 else x) for i, x in enumerate(f.readlines(), 1)]
    f.truncate(0)
    f.seek(0, 0)
    f.writelines(content)
```

Comment: For some reasons it does nothing to the file. the file remains the same format.

Comment: Do you may want to replace `"\n"` instead of `"\r\n"`. Try that and if it still does not work give me an example of the first line printed out after opening and reading the lines. Just to make sure, there is a \r\n in your lines.

Comment: It works perfeclty with \n my bad in notepad++ i tried with \r\n and worked but i guess it is working. Thanks a lot man.

Comment: i was going to also recommend '\n' instead of '\r\n'.  @MisterNox, you are awesome. The list compression was too good :)